# Faut-il utiliser le conditionel présent ou l'indicatif futur dans une phrase où la "condition" a été omise?

Tags: conditionnel, temps-grammatical, futur-simple, mode-grammatical

Je m'interroge sur la validité de la conjugaison du verbe *être* dans l'échange suivant, et j'espère que vous pourrez éclairer ma lanterne. Je cite :

> — Je ne suis pas sûr que tu sois intéressé par les bijoux !
>   — T'as raison. Je **serai** peu intéressé.

À mes yeux, la *condition* du manque d'intérêt est liée aux bijoux. Il me semblerait donc logique que l'on emploie le conditionnel plutôt que le futur dans ce cas, malgré l'absence de la proposition de condition.

En même temps, je sais qu'il ne faut pas forcément être logique en français !

Comment: Hmm, je vois pas quelle est cette condition dont tu parles. Qu'est-ce qui pourrait faire changer ce monsieur d'avis ?

Comment: intuitivement j'aurais dit "j'aurais été"

Comment: Comme Stéphane Gimenez, en l'état je ne vois pas de condition, mais on peut imaginer cette conversation dans un contexte qui impliquerait un conditionnel.

Comment: Je trouve aussi que ça manque un peu de contexte. Peut-on avoir une version plus longue du texte, ou une référence ? En ce qui me concerne, je dirais juste « je suis peu intéressé »".

Comment: Merci pour vos commentaires. C'est un extrait d'une conversation écrite entre deux amis sur un réseau social (recueil de perles grammaticales). La première personne explique qu'elle regarde de jolie choses en vitrine et hésite à acheter quelque chose. La seconde personne lui demande si c'est pour lui qu'elle veut acheter l'une de ses "choses".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le dialogue que tu cites, le verbe *intéresser* dans la réponse peut être au conditionnel présent ou au futur suivant le contexte. Si l'évènement auquel se rapporte le dialogue est un évènement futur certain, le verbe est au futur de l'indicatif :

> — Je vais devoir accompagner ma femme qui veut acheter un collier.
>   — Je ne suis pas sûr que tu sois intéressé par les bijoux!
>   — T'as raison. Je serai peu intéressé. Mais je ne pourrai pas y couper.

Si l'évènement est hypothétique, le verbe est au conditionnel :

> — Ma femme veut m'emmener voir une exposition sur les diamants.
>   — Je ne suis pas sûr que tu sois intéressé par les bijoux!
>   — T'as raison. Je serais peu intéressé. C'est pour ça que je vais essayer d'y échapper.

On peut avoir d'autres temps et mode suivant le contexte. Par exemple, s'il s'agit d'un énoncé général, on utilisera le présent de l'indicatif.

> — Ma femme adore les bijoux.
>   — Je ne suis pas sûr que tu sois intéressé par les bijoux!
>   — T'as raison. Je suis peu intéressé. Je lui en achète de temps en temps, mais je suis les conseils du vendeur et je ne regarde que le prix.

Answer (score 7):

Le problème c'est que dans ton exemple le premier devrait utiliser le subjonctif présent à la voix active (car  à priori c'est un état de fait, donc non fluctuant). La phrase du second induit un « si tu me le proposais » sous-entendu. Donc au présent (sachant qu'il y a une version au passé et au futur possible également) ça donnerait :

> - Je ne suis pas sûr que tu t'intéresses aux bijoux!
>
> - T'as raison. Je serais peu intéressé.

Il existe une variante plus explicite : « que tu te sois jamais intéressé aux bijoux ».
Bref dans tous les cas, pour répondre à ta question, c'est le conditionnel qui prévaut.

Comment: Je n'ai aucune idée de la grammaticalité, mais « Je serais peu intéressé » m'écorche les oreilles.

Comment: @evpok normal comme je l'explique une partie du texte est sous-entendue par le contexte (absente mais induite).

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la première remarque. _que tu sois intéressé_ **est** un subjonctif présent, celui de "être (intéressé)". Je ne suis pas sûr qu'il y ait une [différence entre _que tu t'intésses_, et _que tu sois intéressé_](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/interesser-vs-etre-interesse)

Comment: @rds Exact: je rajoute la différence.

Answer (score 5):

Pour prendre un autre exemple plus banal et sans nécéssité de contexte, on peut comparer:

> Ca m'étonnerait!

Contre:

> Ca m'étonnera!

La condition étant sous-entendue (par exemple: *si mon patron était malade aujourd'hui*), la forme conditionnelle est la plus logique. Utiliser un futur simple impliquerait qu'on est certain que la condition va se produire, ce qui n'est généralement pas le cas. Evidemment, le choix du verbe *étonner* joue ici un rôle : impossible d'être étonné par quelque chose dont on est certain qu'il va arriver.

Dans ton exemple, j'avoue que je suis moins certain qu'il y ait une condition sous-entendue, mais si il y en a une, le conditionnel est le meilleur choix. Sinon, je pense qu'un présent convient mieux, le futur me paraît beaucoup plus douteux (si je serai intéressé par quelque chose demain, je ne vois pas pourquoi ça ne m'intéresse pas aujourd'hui).

Comment: erreur de conjugaison _... qu'il y ait..._

Comment: Diantre, merci.