# Intéresser vs être intéressé

Tags: usage, verbes-pronominaux, passif

En lisant [la réponse de Knu](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/faut-il-utiliser-le-conditionel-present-ou-lindicatif-futur-dans-une-phrase-ou/1597#1597) à une autre question, je m'interroge sur la différence qu'il y a entre *quelque chose m'intéresse* et *je suis intéressé par quelque chose* et *je m'intéresse à quelque chose*.

Au passé simple (Dupanloup, Journal, 1876, p. 34) :

> La logique m'intéressa beaucoup, surtout sur les questions de certitude. Mais ce fut la métaphysique qui m'enleva.

Je reviens au présent pour éviter les archaïsmes du passé simple, et me demande si le sens est différent entre:

- *La logique m'intéresse beaucoup, surtout ...*
- *Je suis très intéressé par la logique, surtout...*
- *Je m'intéresse beaucoup à la logique, surtout...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour moi

> - La logique m'intéresse beaucoup, surtout ...
> - Je suis très intéressé par la logique, surtout...

sont équivalents et décrivent un état intrinsèque, tandis que

> - Je m'intéresse beaucoup à la logique, surtout...

décrit plutôt le résultat de la volonté (*Malgré mon manque d'amour pour le sujet, je me suis intéressé à la logique.* me semble possible.)

Comment: Je vais retenir cette réponse. Sur une personne, la subtilité est-elle plus apparente?  "_Elle m'intéresse; elle est si belle!_" (_Voyage autour de mon jardin_, Alphonse Kaar) vs "_Je m'intéresse à lui , non seulement comme a un homme qui fait honneur à la nation , mais comme à un homme que j'aime de tout mon cœur_" (Voltaire)

Answer (score 1):

Le premier indique que c'est « La logique » qui va vers Dupanloup alors que pour les deux suivants, c'est plutôt l'inverse : c'est Dupanloup qui décide d'aller vers la Logique.

Même si le résultat final est le même, il y a quand même une nuance comme quand on demande a un couple comment ils se sont rencontrés  (Qui a fait le premier pas ?)

Comment: La logique étant un concept, je ne vois pas comment elle pourrait aller vers quoi que ce soit. Peux-tu préciser ?